# pip3 works with python3.2 but won't work with python3.3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have created a virtual environment for python3

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 myenv
```

Everything works ok and pip installs python3 packages. Then I need to upgrade my python3.2 to python3.3. I am using **ubuntu 12.04**, so I need to do what Luper Rouch suggests [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-do-i-install-python-3-3/290283#290283) through ppa

I copy /usr/bin/python3.3 into myenv/bin/python3, thus (inside myenv):

```
python --version
```

returns Python 3.3.5. But then pip stops working failing with

```
pip install urllib3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypathtoevn/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
     from pip import main
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
```

Then I understand that I have to use

```
pip3.3 install <package_name>
```

but I can't find any other pip*.* version either globally or inside virtualenv in my system.

How can I get pip3.3 or any other pip version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ppa you have installed does not contain `pip`. The python package installer is itself installed with `easy_install`. On the question you linked to follow the later parts of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/250056/28323)

Basically, calling

```
wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python distribute_setup.py

easy_install pip
```

should be sufficient. You should use the `easy_install` command of your Python3.3 install.

Check with

```
which python
```

where your python comes from, and search for `easy_install` in that path. In your case you know where it resides: Your virtualenv.

Comment: And starting with Python3.4, use `python -m ensurepip` https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html :)